# How to set color on the position (X,Y) javascript

Tags: javascript, heatmap

I am making a heatmap clicks script which will record the no. of clicks and according to that shows the color on the clicked position. Now I have the positions(X,Y) where the clicks are made, I want to set color on that positon.
Any Idea ?

Something like this:

**GetPosition(X,Y).setColor("any color")**;

Comment: how you will see a color of that pixel position?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your code, where are you stuck?
You may take a look at [heatmapjs](https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/). For visitor tracking heatmap links to [hotjar](https://www.hotjar.com/) which tracks clicks. Both were never used by myself.

Comment: Is the pixel you want do draw in a html5 canvas or elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to draw an HTML5 Canvas you can do something like this:

```
var id = yourContext.createImageData(1, 1);
var data = id.data;
data[0] = red;
data[1] = green;
data[2] = blue;
data[3] = alpha;
yourContext.putImageData(id, x, y);
```